# Image zoom implementation looks laggy (with reproduction)

Tags: reactjs

My implementation of image zoom looks laggy.
What should be optimized?

**Reproduction**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rxnq99?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fstyle.css&title=React%20Starter

Integer coordinates work better without decimals, but it is still laggy;

Code without reproduction:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [initZoomData, setInitZoomData] =
    React.useState<Record<string, number>>();

  const [zoomData, setZoomData] = React.useState<Record<string, number>>({});

  const onImageOver = (e: React.PointerEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
    const image = e.currentTarget;
    const wrapper = image.parentElement;
    if (!wrapper) return;

    const top = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const width = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const height = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const left = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    const scale = 2;
    const coeff = (width * scale) / ((width * scale - width) / 2);

    const centerX = left + width / 2;
    const centerY = top + height / 2;

    setInitZoomData({
      top,
      width,
      height,
      left,
      centerX,
      centerY,
      coeff,
      scale,
    });
  };

  const onImageMove = (e: React.PointerEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
    if (!initZoomData) return;

    const { scale, top, width, height, left, centerX, centerY } = initZoomData;

    let offsetX;
    let offsetY;

    if (e.pageX > centerX) {
      offsetX = ((centerX - e.clientX) / (width / 2)) * 100;
    } else {
      offsetX = 100 - ((e.clientX - left) / (width / 2)) * 100;
    }

    if (e.pageY > centerY) {
      offsetY = ((centerY - e.clientY) / (height / 2)) * 100;
    } else {
      offsetY = 100 - ((e.clientY - top) / (height / 2)) * 100;
    }

    setZoomData({
      scale,
      offsetX,
      offsetY,
    });
  };

  const onImageLeave = () => {
    setInitZoomData(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <div className="imageWrapperInner">
      <img
        style={{
          transform: initZoomData
            ? `scale(${zoomData.scale}) translate(${zoomData.offsetX / 4}%, ${
                zoomData.offsetY / 4
              }%)`
            : 'scale(1)',
        }}
        onPointerOver={onImageOver}
        onPointerMove={onImageMove}
        onPointerLeave={onImageLeave}
        src="https://createx.createx.studio/assets/img/ecommerce/shop/09.jpg"
        alt="Product image."
        className="image"
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow posts should be **self contained** so please don't put crucial information exclusively behind an external link!

Comment: Remove the `transition` from your CSS and it's no longer laggy.